# EXCEL - object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a spreadsheet that pulls in the current price from a website and records it. I am getting the "object variable or with block variable not set" error on this line:

```
costForGame = appIE.document.getElementById("used_price").getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText     'Finds "used_price" and then any span within it and returns the first value
```

I am not sure what my issue is, or how to fix it. Thoughts?

```
Sub ImportUsedPrice()
Dim Console As String
Dim GameTitle As String
Dim URL As String
Dim costForGame As Double

Range("G3").Clear                   'clears D3
Range("H3").Clear
Range("J3").Clear
Range("K3").Clear


'creates web browser
Dim appIE As Object
Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

Dim indexB As Single
Dim indexC As Single
Dim nameCell As String
Dim consoleCell As String

indexB = 3
indexC = 3

nameCell = "B" & indexB
consoleCell = "C" & indexC

While IsEmpty(nameCell) = False And IsEmpty(consoleCell) = False

    Range("J3").Value = IsEmpty(nameCell)      'used for debugging
    Range("K3").Value = IsEmpty(consoleCell)   'used for debugging
    Range("G3").Value = indexB                 'used for debugging
    Range("H3").Value = indexC                 'used for debugging

    'access the webpage
    Console = Range(consoleCell).Value
    GameTitle = Range(nameCell).Value
    URL = "http://www.pricecharting.com/game/" & Console & "/" & GameTitle          'makes complete URL
    With appIE
        .Navigate URL
        .Visible = True            'True shows the browser, False does not
    End With

    'wait for the page to load
    Do While appIE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop

    'pull the data
    costForGame = appIE.document.getElementById("used_price").getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText     'Finds "used_price" and then any span within it and returns the first value
    Range("D3").Value = costForGame         'records price in D3

    indexB = indexB + 1
    indexC = indexC + 1
Wend

appIE.Quit                  'Closes Internet Explorer
Set appIE = Nothing         'Release memory for IE

Range("D3").Select          'selects cell D3
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select          'selects cell D3 and all cells below it
Selection.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"            'formats all selected cells to dollars

End Sub
```

Comment: Over my head but you _created_ `Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")` yet never set the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this two lines:

```
Do While appIE.Busy
```

to

```
Do Until appIE.ReadyState = 4
```

and also

```
costForGame = appIE.document.getElementById("used_price").getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
```

to

```
costForGame = Replace(appIE.document.getElementById("used_price").Children(1).innerText, "$", "")
```

**EDIT**

First off `Children(1)` needs to be `Children(0)`. But even using IE11, the `appIE.Busy` will be false before the site is loaded completely. My version is 11.306.10586.0 with update-version 11.0.31 and `appIE.ReadyState` works like a charm. Here the full code I have used to test your sub. (runned without errors)

```
Sub ImportUsedPrice()
Dim Console As String
Dim GameTitle As String
Dim URL As String
Dim costForGame As Double

Range("G3").Clear                   'clears D3
Range("H3").Clear
Range("J3").Clear
Range("K3").Clear


'creates web browser
Dim appIE As Object
Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

Dim indexB As Single
Dim indexC As Single
Dim nameCell As String
Dim consoleCell As String

indexB = 3
indexC = 3

nameCell = "B" & indexB
consoleCell = "C" & indexC

'While IsEmpty(nameCell) = False And IsEmpty(consoleCell) = False

    Range("J3").Value = IsEmpty(nameCell)      'used for debugging
    Range("K3").Value = IsEmpty(consoleCell)   'used for debugging
    Range("G3").Value = indexB                 'used for debugging
    Range("H3").Value = indexC                 'used for debugging

    'access the webpage
    Console = Range(consoleCell).Value
    GameTitle = Range(nameCell).Value
    'URL = "http://www.pricecharting.com/game/" & Console & "/" & GameTitle          'makes complete URL
    URL = "https://www.pricecharting.com/game/playstation-3/grand-theft-auto-v"

    With appIE
        .Navigate URL
        .Visible = True            'True shows the browser, False does not
    End With

    'wait for the page to load
    'Do While appIE.Busy
    Do Until appIE.ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    'pull the data
    'costForGame = appIE.document.getElementById("used_price").getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText     'Finds "used_price" and then any span within it and returns the first value
    costForGame = Replace(appIE.document.getElementById("used_price").Children(0).innerText, "$", "")
    Range("D3").Value = costForGame         'records price in D3

    indexB = indexB + 1
    indexC = indexC + 1
'Wend

appIE.Quit                  'Closes Internet Explorer
Set appIE = Nothing         'Release memory for IE

Range("D3").Select          'selects cell D3
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select          'selects cell D3 and all cells below it
Selection.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"            'formats all selected cells to dollars

End Sub
```

Comment: I made those changes, and am now getting an error saying "Method 'Document' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed" and the debug line is 
costForGame = Replace(appIE.document.getElementById("used_price").Children(1).innerText, "$", "")                         I also looked up the ReadyState line you suggested and found that that is no longer supported in IE 11. Could that be part of my issue?

Comment: Please see my edited answer and check if that helps or causes other errors.